# Android Google+ Login, works on one device but other device gets "internal error has occurred"

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, integration

I have the Google+ login integrated with my android app, and the app successfully runs on my emulator, but when I try to run the app on a different device, I get `"an internal error has occurred"`.  Is there any reason why it would work on my computer but not my device?

I followed the Google+ login creation steps from

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

EDIT:

I already filled out the consent screen and the Client ID, that's why it's able to work on the emulator.  Is it possible that I used the wrong SHA1 key in the Client ID, and that's why it only works on one device?

Comment: Did you fill the consent screen in API console? [link](http://blacode.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/android-google-login-an-internal-error-occcurred/)

Comment: make sure a google acount is added to device

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you haven't set the signature for the client ID in your API console project, or if you copied the wrong key value.

Also in developer console check that the consent screen has both product name and Email set.

Comment: Would the wrong key value make it work on one device and not the other?